# How am I intended to navigate the constellations?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When picking a perk to level up, I have to click once per constellation if I want to change which skill I want a perk in. If I want to go to a skill a few constellations away, it is burdensome to click and wait for the animation to slide the constellations over and then click again.

Once within a constellation, picking which branch of the tree you navigate down seems finicky as well. Navigating back down the tree to the base or out of the constellation altogether is just as cumbersome.

Is there some set of controls for navigating this screen that I am unaware of? The arrow keys on the keyboard don't seem to do anything, like they do in other menus. Is there something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can navigate the constellations with the keyboard using the WASD keys, which may be easier than trying to use the mouse , which have a tendency to click on the wrong star.

If you have problem reaching a star, you should try approaching it from another direction, like going from the side, or even another constellation.

Comment: The WASD(and in most other screens the arrow keys) are by far easier to navigate with.  +1 for recommending that.

Comment: The mouse-wheel can also be used in place of the W and S keys.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the problem of being unable to reach certain stars using the WASD keys but I then discovered this: The mouse also works. You can simply click on the "stars" that you are having difficulty scrolling to with the keyboard. If a star is not on screen, try navigating to a star that is on the same "latitude" and navigate to it using the A and D keys.

Comment: In the Illusion tree, there is one star off to the left, off the screen when you zoom into the constellation, and thus impossible to click on.

Comment: Maybe the star is an illusion itself.